# Is there a difference between the powers of magicians who can control fire like Stiyl Magnus and esper who does like Okahara Ryouta?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

In Toaru Majutsu no Index , there are magicians and espers who can control fire like Stiyl Magnus and Okahara Ryouta. Is there a difference between their powers since they belong to different classifications or can they basically do the same?